# Django ORM and chained select_related

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

How do I do this query with Django ORM?

It is a multiple join, chained from table to table.

The Django documentation about select related (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) gives an example where three tables are "chained" via foreign keys: Book -> Author -> City.

saying

> b = Book.objects.select_related('author__hometown').get(id=4)
>
> p = b.author         # Doesn't hit the database.
>
> c = p.hometown       # Doesn't hit the database.

to "not hit the database" must mean that select query joins the three tables. 
Therefore the sql generated by the query should show that (I have not yet checked).

My models are based on analysis of an existing database, with well-defined foreign keys.
I'll extracts of the models below.

```
SELECT *
     FROM  SERVICE 
     INNER JOIN VISIT ON SERVICE.VisitRecordID = VISIT.VisitRecordID 
     INNER JOIN  CMPATIENT ON VISIT.PatientNo = CM_PATIENT.PATIENT_ID
```

The first join I can do with

```
q = Service.objects.select_related('visitrecordid',).all()
```

which makes sql like:

```
SELECT * FROM [SERVICE] LEFT OUTER JOIN [VISIT] ON ([SERVICE].[VisitRecordID] = [VISIT].[VisitRecordID])
```

so I am getting left outer joins, not inner joins, which is one question.
But most of all, I don't know why CmPatient is not involved in the query.

Models (extracts)

```
class Service(models.Model):
    servrecid = models.AutoField(db_column='ServRecID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    visitrecordid = models.ForeignKey('Visit', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='VisitRecordID', blank=True,
                                      null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    itemno = models.CharField(db_column='ItemNo', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.


class Visit(models.Model):
    visitrecordid = models.AutoField(db_column='VisitRecordID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    patientno = models.ForeignKey(CmPatient, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='PatientNo', blank=True,
                                  null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    visitdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='VisitDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    servdoctor = models.CharField(db_column='ServDoctor', max_length=6, blank=True,
                                  null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.


class CmPatient(models.Model):
    patient_id = models.AutoField(db_column='PATIENT_ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ur_no = models.CharField(db_column='UR_NO', max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    external_id = models.CharField(db_column='EXTERNAL_ID', max_length=9, blank=True,
                                   null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    payer = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='PAYER_ID', blank=True,
                              null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Comment: Can you share your django models and the data (i.e. columns) you're trying to pull in this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse the relationship via `__` (two underscores). So what you want is:

```
Service.objects.select_related('visitrecordid__patientno')
```

Comment: thanks, I now realise I have no idea how to read documentation.

Comment: Side question, are you integrating with an existing database? Your models aren't defined as I'd expect to find "normal" django models defined. Specifically the <model>_id as the ids, the usage of db_column and defining the foreign keys as patientno and visitrecordid (patient or cm_patient and visit are what I'd suggest respectively).

Comment: You're right, the models  were created by running manage.py inspectdb on a large database. It did a pretty good job too.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then ignore my suggestion. Well sort of. I'd still likely rename the relationship fields so it makes more sense in terms of an ORM.

Comment: update: I have learnt a lot about this feature in the past few days. Good news: it works. Bad news: it doesn't follow reverse foreign key relationships, I am experimenting with a hack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59124549/django-orm-select-related-fooling-reverse-foreign-key-with-a-fake-foreign-key

Comment: Use `prefetch_related` in those cases.